# C - Difference between quotation and apostrophe ( " vs ' )

Tags: c, syntax

In C it has come to attention that there is a difference between these 2 specified syntax. Observe

```
 char test[5] = {"c", "o", "o", "l", "\0"}; // with quotation
```

bring about error:

```
error: (near initialization for 'test')
error: excess elements in char array initializer
error: (near initialization for 'test')
error: excess elements in char array initializer
error: (near initialization for 'test')
error: excess elements in char array initializer
error: (near initialization for 'test')
```

Where as

```
char test[5] = {'c', 'o', 'o', 'l', '\0'}; // with apostrophe
```

Compiles finely. What is the cause of this?

Comment: `'x'` is a character literal. `"x"` is a string literal containing one character.

Comment: Single characters versus strings (sequences of characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in this array are *characters* (1 byte each):

`char test[5] = {'c', 'o', 'o', 'l', '\0'};`

This is a null-terminated C string.  It's represented exactly the same way in memory.  It consists of exactly 5 bytes: the letters "cool", and the terminating null character:

`char test2[5] = {"cool"};`

And this consists of two bytes:

`char test3[] = "c";`

Your original example is an array of 2-byte strings.  Unlike the previous examples, it's actually a 2-level array.  You must declare it as such:

`char *test[] = {"c", "o", "o", "l", "\0"};`

Comment: @Blastfurnace - that was a typo,  Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2):

In C, when you are using single quotes then it means a character and a double quotes means string literal. And since you declared your array as char hence it cannot store string in that.

Answer (score 2):

"x" is not a character, Its a string literal. It is same as an array of two characters `'x'` and `'\0'`.

I think of it like this:

```
       _ _ _ _ _
"x" => |'x'|'\0'| 
       - - - - -
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char test[5] = {'c', 'o', 'o', 'l', '\0'}; // with apostrophe
```

is the correct syntax because, as you have declared, test is an array of characters which can store 5 characters.

char* test[5] = {"c", "o", "o", "l", "\0"}; // with quotation

This is acceptable, since you are declaring that test is an array of pointers to character strings.

Run the following code in ideone.com and see.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
// your code goes here

char* teststring[5] = {"c", "o", "o", "l", "\0"}; // with quotation

char testchar[5] = {'c', 'o', 'o', 'l', '\0'};
printf("%s\n", teststring[2]);

printf("%c\n", testchar[2]);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C,

Two single quotes, `'`, are used to represent a character constant.
Two double quotes, `"`, are used to represent a string literal.

A character constant can represent one character only. `'ab'` is not a valid character constant.

A string literal can contain multiple characters.